# multivariate convergence in law

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $X_n \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longrightarrow} X$, and $Y$ is another random variable which may be depending on $X_n$. Then it seems not true that we have the following joint convergence in law
$$(X_n,Y) \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longrightarrow} (X,Y).$$
But who can give me a counter example to this?

Comment: Hint: if you replace $X$ with any other random variable $X'$ that has the same distribution, then you also have $X_n \overset{\mathscr{L}}{\longrightarrow} X'$.  But $(X',Y)$ could have a very different joint distribution from $(X,Y)$.

Comment: Thanks! I would take $X'$ identically distributed as $X$ but independent of $X$, then the distribution of $(X,Y)$ and $(X',Y)$ could be different.

Answer (score 2):

Here is perhaps the minimal counterexample.

Let $X$ be a random variable taking the values $\pm 1$ each with   probability  1/2. Set $X_n =X$ for every $n$. Also set $Y=X$.

Now clearly $X_n \to X$ in law. But since $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution, it's equally true that $X_n \to -X$ in law. Now you can check that $(X_n, X)$ does not converge in law to $(-X, X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much!( BTW,Did you receive your ph.d from UCSD? I also got my master degree there, working with Prof. R.Williams.)

Comment: @Sean: I did!  My advisor was Bruce Driver, but I took several classes from Professor Williams.

Comment: Haha! The world is so small!